# How do i send data from one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting the problem in sending data and id from one jsp page to another jsp page. Actualy i want to send data and id from first jsp(a.jsp) page to second jsp(b.jsp) page.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to send data from one JSP to another

**1.**

```
String name="Hello";

request.setAttribute("Name",name);
```

From Another JSP Access by:

```
request.getAttribute("Name");//Hello
```

**2.**

```
String name="Hello";

session.setAttribute("Name",name);
```

From Another JSP Access by:

```
session.getAttribute("Name");//Hello
```

**3.**

```
String name="Hello";

localStorage.setItem("Name",name);
```

From Another JSP Access by:

```
localStorage.getItem("Name")//Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **sessions** to store data that can then be accessed by any page.

**In your servlet:**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

To set data in session *(page a)*:

```
String data = "myDataAsString";
session.setAttribute("myData", data );
```

To read data from session *(page b)*:

```
String data = (String) session.getAttribute("myData");
```