# Secure way of passing data from one jsp to another

Tags: jsp

I have done some research, and majority of the answers say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148257/11997761) and also by passing data as request parameters.

My question is which of these is the most secure way of achieving the same?

Comment: What do you mean with _most secure way_?

Comment: By secure, I mean data is safe. Basically which method you'd recommend me to implement?

Comment: I would use request attributes and (if you want to be completely safe) verify it in the jsp